# When do you use differential equations?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a problem whose answer I find rather questionable in my textbook.

> A psychologist has determined that the initial probability of success for a given exam is 0.02, and that the maximum amount learned is 0.86.
>
> After studying 1 month, probability of success increases to 0.23
>
> Within how many months studying will the probability reach 0.70?

The answer to this exercise is formulated as a differential function.

I do not see the need to differentiate as there is no indication of non-linearity.

Can't I simply go

$$\frac{0.23 - 0.2}{1\text{ (month)}}$$

Rate of learning is $0.21/\text{month}$, so it will take

$$\frac{0.70-0.2}{0.21} = 3.24$$

months to reach 0.70.

How is this process incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that's all it says (with no previous discussion of models for learning), this is a very poorly formulated exercise.  There is no
indication that the probability of success should satisfy any particular kind of differential equation.

You could say that this is 
also a feature of real-life research: nature does not tell you what kind of 
model to use.  However, in a real situation a researcher might look at a bunch of
data, try to find a reasonable model, and test that model against more data.  Here you  don't have that.

Comment: It's in the differential equations section of the book, so I know that I'm expected to use a differential equation. However I don't see the use here, and I find it unfortunate that they didn't take the effort to model the problem in such a way that it illustrates the use of the topic.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure that I wasn't misunderstanding the question. Thx

Answer (score 2):

There is no mention of "non-linearity" but there is also no mention of "linearity"!  NOT given in the statement of the problem but generally true is that learning obeys a "logistic equation".  That is a differential equation of the form $dx/dt= Ax(T- x)$.  That is, when $x$ is close to $0$, when you are just starting to learn a field, the rate of learning is low, as you become more familiar with the subject, learning becomes easier, but eventually, as $x$ nears $T$, the total information of the field, learning becomes harder again.

Comment: Ha! Fascinating! Thanks for the info. Will definitely use that as an answer to mind boggle my teacher ...

Comment: What evidence do you have that learning obeys a logistic equation?